# Concatenate result element of JMESpath multiselect filter with a variable

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, jmespath

I have following variable structure in Ansible (YAML format):

```
my_groups:
  - name: g1
    users:
      - name: foo
        param: rock
        junk: whatever

      - name: bar
        param: paper 
        junk: whatever

  - name: g2
    users:
      - name: baz
        param: scissors
        junk: whatever
```

And I need to transform it to flat array of `users` that looks like this (note the `1` in each `name`):

```
- name: foo1
  param: rock

- name: bar1
  param: paper 

- name: baz1
  param: scissors
```

I use *Jinja* filter `json_query` (which internally use *JMESPath* query language in Python) like this:

```
{{ my_groups|json_query( "[*].users[*].{ name: name, param: param }" ) }}
```

Which returns the array mentioned above but without the `1` in the name of course. Is there some way how to achieve the desired concatenation with a simple string? I tried some variants due to documentation and examples but with no luck i.e.:

```
{{ my_groups|json_query( "[*].users[*].{ name: name + '1', param: param }" ) }}
```

Simple Ansible playbook is available at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gdHFqmL1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JMESPath has [join](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) built-in to convert list into string.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_groups | json_query(qry) }}"
  vars:
    qry: "[*].users[*][].{ name: join('',[name,'1']), param: param }"
```

Also note `[]` after `users[*]` to flatten the list.

Result:

```
"msg": [
    {
        "name": "foo1",
        "param": "rock"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar1",
        "param": "paper"
    },
    {
        "name": "baz1",
        "param": "scissors"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried `join` function but i missed the trick with _empty join string_.

Comment: Anyone please note that there is some [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299) in recent Ansible version. You need to use `{{ my_groups | to_json | from_json | json_query(qry) }}` workaround.

Comment: Confirm Vojta's comment. Just adding `|to_json|from_json|` just before `json_query` fixes the issues with expected types